# Usar clases utilitarias estáticas

Tags: java, mockito, junit-5, spring-webflux

¿En qué casos se recomienda usar este tipo de clases? Si por ejemplo, quiero validar el **request** , validar ciertos valores para de acuerdo a ello, enviar una respuesta al Frontend. ¿Debería de usar una clase estática? Si es así, ¿cómo haría el **test** del método service que usa una clase utilitaria? Dado que un **stub**, sólo acepta **mocks**.

```
class Service {
    public Person returnAny(Request request) {
        return UtilClass.validate(request).
             switchIfEmpty(...)
             .map(...);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

En general, evita usar clases Utility, ya que van en contra de algunos principios de la POO.

En tu código tienes un servicio para obtener una Persona:

- Si la request es una *HttpRequest* que viene de un controlador, es responsabilidad del controlador validar la request.
- Si la request es un objeto creado específicamente para tu servicio (un query command), es responsabilidad del servicio (o de la propia clase Request) validar la información de ese objeto, con lo que el método debería ser privado de la clase Service/Request.

Por otro lado, si llamas a métodos estáticos (que deben ser *stateless* (sin estado), ya sea de una Utility class o de la propia clase, trata ese código como parte de tu clase, ya que nada debería evitar que pudieses copiar y pegar ese método a tu clase y marcarlo como privado: No deberías tratar de *mockearlo*.

Comment: el `RequestBody` es envíado por el frontend y la clase `Controller` lo recibe, es ahí donde se invoca al `Service` (y donde tengo entendido se realiza la lógica de negocio, no en el controlador) y finalmente en éste se invoca a otra clase de otra capa que se comunica con otra API Rest. ¿Por qué hacer la lógica de validación en el `Controller` ? ¿Si tengo varios `endpoints` y necesito métodos "utilitarios" los pondría todos bien en el `Service` o `Controller` y no sería engorroso?

Comment: Imagina que tienes un nuevo controller que requiere hacer una tarea y necesita usar el mismo service: la request sería distinta. O que otro service requiera obtener información de este Service, directamente no habría un objeto request. El código de tu service sólo se debe encargar de la lógica de negocio, pero no de traducir las peticiones o las respuestas al protocolo con el que tu aplicación se comunica con otras aplicaciones o usuarios, esa es la lógica de comunicación, no de negocio